# Are literature reviews necessary for journal articles?

Tags: publications, journals, writing

A journal states that literature reviews should be 5000-8000 words, but mine is 10k. Should I omit the literature review and only state the problem?

Comment: What does _only depends on problems statement_ mean? I tried to clarify with an edit. I also reworded other aspects. Please edit further if necessary.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Omitting the literature review is highly unlikely to help you: You must position your contribution with respect to the literature. Submitting a manuscript with a literature review that is too long might be tolerable. (Perhaps check other articles and see whether they comply with the length requirement.) Alternatively, you should reduce the length of your literature review.